# Cubic perturbation to coupled quantum harmonic oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory, coupled-oscillators

I recently came across this two-dimensional problem of a particle in a potential of the form
$$V = \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}m \omega^2} \big(y^2 + x^2y \big) - \alpha y,$$
where $x$ and $y$ are known to be small, and I was trying to solve the time-independent Schroedinger equation,
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2} \right) + (y^2 + x^2y ) \psi - \alpha y\, \psi = E \psi,$$
to obtain the wavefunction $\psi$ and the corresponding allowed energy levels.

My initial attempt at a solution was to treat the $x^2y$ term as a perturbation. Retaining just the $y^2 - \alpha y$ term, I obtain the zeroth-order wavefunction and energy levels as

$$E^{(0)}_n = \left( n + \frac{1}{2}\hbar \omega \right) + \frac{p_x^2}{2m},$$

$$\psi^{(0)}_{n} =  \mathrm{e}^{i\, p_x / \hbar} \;\mathrm{H}_n \bigg(\sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{\hbar}} \rho \bigg) \mathrm{e}^{\displaystyle{\frac{-m \omega \rho^2}{2 \hbar}}},$$

where $\rho$ equals $y$ minus some easily calculable constant. However, the main problem arises when I try to calculate the first-order energy-levels
$$E^{(1)}_n = \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}m \omega^2}\langle \psi^{(0)}_n \,\lvert \, x^2y \,\rvert\, \psi^{(0)}_n \rangle.$$
This integral obviously cannot be evaluated since the $x^2$ term, when integrated from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, diverges. Moreover, since the additional term is cubic, I also cannot employ [a change of coordinates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135514/coupled-quantum-harmonic-oscillator) to decouple the system.

Hence, I was wondering if there exists some clean method by which one can solve this problem. I would really appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: If I see this correctly, the third order term is not bound from below and there is no ground state. One could probably still calculate the decay time of a wave packet, as it "leaks" out of the potential?

Comment: It is indeed true that for the third-order term alone, there is no ground state. However calculation of the decay time, as done herein (http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0703234.pdf) would involve the initial length of the box in which the particle is confined. What if this is on an unbounded domain?

Comment: I think it would make sense to perform time dependent perturbation theory and to turn the third order term on at $t>0$ using the unperturbed solutions as initial wave function.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I am not very familiar with time-dependent perturbation theory so could you please expand upon your comment in an answer? It would be really very helpful if you could explain how to proceed with the problem.

Comment: You can evaluate the action of the perturbation terms on the eigenstates of the unperturbed solutions. Since the ground state decays very quickly in both x and y directions, the integrals should all be convergent (just guessing here). That will give you the time scale on which those states decay into free (in this case accelerated along the y-axis?) solutions.